# Fire get method again once javascript object has been populated

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I have the following:

**head.js**

```js
export class Header{
    customer={};

  getCustomerData(){
    this.customer={
      first:'test',
      middle:'middle',
      last:'test'
    }
  }

  activate() {
      getCustomerData();
  }
  get customerFullName(){
    return `${this.customer.first} ${this.customer.middle} ${this.customer.last}`;
  }
}
```

**head.html**

```html
<div class="head">
    ${customerFullName}
</div>
```

So the customer object is empty initially, and isnt populated until activate() is fired. This means that on first entry to the screen, the div is blank, but doesn't update after getCustomerData() is fired. How do i either make customerFullName dependent on activate(i.e. only fire this method once activate() is finished), or get customerFullName to fire again once customer has data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's a bug in the code- the activate method should have `this.getCustomerData();` instead of `getCustomerData();`.

If you want to delay the binding/rendering of the template until after the customer data has been loaded you should return a promise from the activate method like this: `return this.getCustomerData();` (assuming your real `getCustomerData` returns a promise).

Here's a working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/kBHq4p?p=preview

Comment: I see, My method does not return a promise as it stands, if you have the time could you alter it to use a promise, so i can see how that would work in my use case?